# How to chain Ubuntu bootloader with openSUSE bootloader with LUKS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption, luks

I have an openSUSE Tumbleweed setup in LUKS with LVMs on `/dev/sda2`, and the bootloader is stored in `/dev/sda1`.

I would like to install Kubuntu 14.04 to a separate hard-drive (in this case /dev/sdc). Ideally the Kubuntu setup can also be run from a LUKS setup. The hard drive in this case has already been prepared with the required `/`, `home` and `swap` partitions.

How can I set up a boot-loading regime which allows both distributions to maintain their own separate bootloading schemes, by having an independent bootloader managing the grub setup for both distributions?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a quick and dirty setup with both grub bootloaders in use. I installed both bootloaders in their separate partitions on their respective drives.

The bootloader for openSUSE was installed in `/dev/sda1` and the bootloader for Kubuntu in `/dev/sdc1`.

Since I haven't yet figured out how to get Kubuntu to recognise the full disk LUKS installation of openSUSE, I instead used openSUSE as the primary boot loader. It also helps that as I only encrypted the `/home` folder for Kubuntu instead of the full disk encryption I did for openSUSE, which made it easier for the openSUSE boot loader to find the other OS.